# Qual é a origem do sinal gráfico trema?

Tags: ortografia, gramática, escrita

Gostaria de saber qual é a origem do sinal gráfico "trema". Por acaso é um sinal de origem grega?

Comment: Pergunto-me se o falecido trema da língua portuguesa não teria a  mesma origem do "umlaut" alemão e do "tréma" francês.  Esse diacrítico é também encontrado no grego.  Já na língua portuguesa, o falecimento ocorreu há alguns anos.

Comment: @tucasilvapontes11584. Concordo. Quando aprendi o Português, lá nos anos 90, a trema era vivíssima e gozava de boa saúde. Depois disso me dediquei às ciências exatas e não consigo escrever _cinquenta_ ou _linguiça_ sem trema. Parece que estou trcando um _ss_ por um _ç_, comendo um erro severo de ortografia!

Comment: @gmauch  Fazer o que?   Eu custei a me livrar do acento grave em "somente".

Comment: Olhe, essa mania de tentar se liberar de acentos ou letras mudas (sou a favor da permanência delas em muitos casos) que podem não parecer importantes, mas fazem uma diferença danada, precisa imediatamente parar, porque isto no futuro, se continuar assim, nos trará sérios problemas de saúde, pelo menos no que diz respeito aos brasileiros. Daqui a pouco, escreveremos com um X como fazem os analfabetos ou pior ainda, com os dedos, quando estes gramáticos ou lingüistas não tiverem mais nada a suprimir no idioma português.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O trema teve de facto origem na Grécia no período helenístico. Tinha dois nomes: *diaíresis* (διαίρεσις, *diérese* em português) , que significa ‘divisão’, ‘separação’, ou ‘distinção’; ou *trēma* (τρῆμα), que significa ‘buraco’ ou ‘ponto num dado’. O último nome refere-se à aparência; o primeiro refere-se à função, que era indicar que a vogal sobre a qual era colocado era pronunciada separadamente da vogal anterior, e não juntamente com ela num ditongo. O *umlaut* alemão, graficamente igual, tem origem e função diferente. [(*Diaeresis* na Wikipedia em inglês.)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_(diacritic))

Nas línguas europeias ocidentais o trema aparece no século XII nalguns documentos anglo-normandos, onde era grafado como um acento agudo duplo. No francês começou a ser usado no século XVI, e mantém-se até hoje. Aparece por exemplo em palavras como *maïs* (‘milho), para indicar que o ***a*** e o ***i*** são pronunciados em duas sílabas (/ma.is/) e não num só som como em *mais* (‘mas’, pronunciado /mɛ/). [(*Tréma* na Wikipedia em francês.)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr%C3%A9ma)

No português, o trema foi prescrito no [acordo de 1943](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&version=1943), para indicar (com umas exceções) nos grupos *gue, gui, que, qui* o ***u*** pronunciado (*agüentar, freqüente*) e opcionalmente em palavras como *saüdade* quando se quer que o ***au*** seja pronunciado como duas sílabas e não como ditongo. Em Portugal o trema praticamente morreu à nascença: foi abolido na reforma de 1945. No Brasil, o uso em casos como *saüdade* foi abolido em 1971; e foi totalmente abolido no acordo de 1990.[(*Trema* na Wikipédia.)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trema#L.C3.ADnguas_que_adotavam_o_trema)